# Define build order on build machine

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I know that I can define a specific build order using dependencies in Visual Studio, but my question is do those dependencies and build order stay the same whenever I check-in my work to TFS and run a build on the TFS server? I ask because I am having some issues when it comes to having multiple projects in the same solution where project B references project A, and project C references project B, etc.

The solution builds locally just fine because I have set the dependencies such that project B always builds first, but it doesn't seem like this configuration carries over to TFS.

Is this possible to do on the TFS build side?

Comment: Building projects in order based on their dependencies on each other is a fairly basic aspect of building, and TFS does that fine on all the projects I've seen. What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Do you reference binary output in the other projects bin folder or do you use project references?

Comment: Make sure you are building the same configuration/platform pair as you are in your dev environment, some configuration don't build in the same order.  For example if you are building in Debug on your dev machine and release in Team Build that might change build orders.

Answer (score 1):

TF Build will build your projects in the same order, dependency order, that they are built in Visual Studio.

If you reference a project (no reference a projects output but the project) then it will all cascade correctly. Direct Binary references do not cascade correctly as both VS and MSBuild assume it is already built.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your updated solution file, with the build order, Is committed to TFS.

Ensure that your build is targeting this solution file rather than a list of projects.

As others have said Project References are the key, check all references point to the project and not the binary output.

If the references are correct then the build order will be correct automatically and manual intervention is only really required for projects such as wix projects where the installer project should always be built last after all of the other outputs have been completed.